# Jest Test - unique "key" prop error. Check the render method of xyz

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a jest test passing but getting the 'array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.' errir

I have found this is caused by a component not having a key prop defined but the component I am testing does.

```
            if (width) {
                arrayList = listings.map(function (listing, i) {
                    return <div className="col"><ListingSimple key={i} listing={listing} displayType={displayType} /></div>;
                });
            }
            else {
                arrayList = listings.map(function (listing, i) {
                    return <ListingSimple key={i} listing={listing} displayType={displayType} />;
                });
            }
```

In my test I have passed in all required props for the rest of the component. It is just giving the console.error for the above. arrayList is getting set properly and I can see my single or multiple list I am just having a blocker on this error.

Just trying to removed this
console.error...

> Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of... See fb react-warning-keys website for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The key needs to be on the outermost child that’s being returned (the `div` in this case).

Comment: I tried the above by my test still threw the error. I also updated the code snip because it is wrapped in an else statement that does not have an outermost child.

Comment: In your updated code, are you sure you're hitting the `else` case? What's the value of width if you console.log it? Either way, you should have the `key` on the `div` in the `if (width)` case. You might need to post a bit more of your code to give the full context. What does your test look like? What does the rest of this component look like?

Comment: the component is big. Let me clean it up to see if I can show the important stuff and will post my test.

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding the key to the wrapper div, like this:

```
if (width) {
            arrayList = listings.map(function (listing, i) {
                return <div key={i} className="col"><ListingSimple key={i} listing={listing} displayType={displayType} /></div>;
            });
        }
        else {
            arrayList = listings.map(function (listing, i) {
                return <ListingSimple key={i} listing={listing} displayType={displayType} />;
            });
        }
```